# Is it possible to make this grid result using flex?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

How can i reproduce this grid that has equal width and height using only flex classes?

[image]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Test1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Test1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Test1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Test1</div>
</div>
```

When i tried to follow the flex documentation, i ended up with this:

[image]

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
   <div class="p-2">Google</div>
   <div class="p-2">Apple</div>
   ...
</div>
```

Simple example of what i want to achieve, first is what i could do with bootstrap grid and the second one is what i could do but without the equal width and height

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style></style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div style="background-color: red" class="col">Google</div>
    <div style="background-color: white" class="col">Apple</div>
    <div style="background-color: red" class="col">Goldman Sachs</div>
    <div style="background-color: white" class="col">Test1</div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  
  <div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
    <div style="background-color: red" class="p-2 flex-shrink-0">Google</div>
    <div style="background-color: white" class="p-2 flex-shrink-0">Apple</div>
    <div style="background-color: red" class="p-2 flex-shrink-0">Goldman Sachs</div>
    <div style="background-color: white" class="p-2 flex-shrink-0">Test1</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try adding `flex-shrink: 0` to the items.

Comment: @Michael_B I don't see any difference after adding shrink

Comment: Then post the full code, so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Where exactly are you telling the browser (in second/flexbox markup): *"I want 4 equal items per row"*? And, since you aren't, why are you expecting it to know?

Comment: @tao That's why i asked, i don't know how could i tell the browser to do it. I know how to do it with grids but not flex

Comment: Apply `flex: 1 0 25%` to children. a.k.a `flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 0; flex-basis: 25%`. or `0 0 25%` if you don't want the ones on last row to grow & fill the entire row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have four equally sized children/row inside a wrapping flex container you have to apply
`flex-shrink: 0; flex-grow: 0; flex-basis: 25%` to each child. Or, in shorthand form:

```
flex: 0 0 25%;
```

Recommended guide: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).